# How can I use 1920 X 1200 HighRes Mode (on a Macbook Pro)?

Tags: macbook-pro, resolution, display

with some quick hack we can easily enable 1920 X 1080 HighRes mode on OS X 10.9.2. However, most Macbook Pro (Retina) today have 16 by 10 screens. How can we do a quick hack and modify the 1920 X 1080 HighRes to 1920 X 1200? I imagine it wouldn't be very hard!

Comment: What hack do you mean by "with some quick hack we can easily enable 1920 X 1080 HighRes mode on OS X 10.9.2"?

Comment: Well, there are a number of applications you can use...also you can override some system files. A google search should bring you at least three ways to do it. I personally like to use RDM. It's a simple and lightweight app. There are some advance apps too, you can try them - but none of them will enable 1920 X 1200 HiDPI.

Comment: I think its because your display can't support that much.

Comment: My display is native 2560X1600 so it does support 1920X1200 HiDPI - in fact, up until OSX 10.7, I can enable 1920X1200 HiDPI mode with system file override.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is solved. Credit goes to Jimmy Ying 'ayeying' (https://twitter.com/ayeying). He says, **"I don't have the 13" Retina MacBook Pro anymore. All you need to do is add 3840x2400 in SwitchResX. This automatically enables 1920x1200 HiDPI."**

So all we need to do is to manually install a 3840x2400 profile to the system (you can use SwitchResX or whatever you want).